# How rewriting for directory in root directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to change my url. Here I have a directory structure like this

```
htdocs/
      example/
              public/
                     login.php
                     people/
                            people1.php
                            people2.php
                     animal/
                            animal1.php
                            animal2.php
                     404.php
              assets/
                    css/
                    js/
```

then I want the url like below in accordance with the existing directory in the root

```
localhost/example/login
localhost/example/people/people1
localhost/example/people/people2
localhost/example/animal/animal1
localhost/example/animal/animal2
```

I've tried making an **.htaccess** file with the following contents

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/(.*)
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/(.*)
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

and it's index.php

```
$requested = empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? false : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ( $requested ) {

    case '/login':
        include 'public/login.php';
        break;
    default:
        include 'public/404.php';
}
```

when I headed localhost/example/login, but destination is **404.php** (ERROR).

can you help me?

Comment: So you have some `rewritecond` ... where is the `rewriterule`?

Comment: @AndyJones can you check again my question?

Comment: You tried http://localhost/example/login? Or something else? Do you dump `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` somewhere in your 404.php page?

Comment: @AndyJones yes, I do and it's value is /self-system/login. so I must write in conditional like "case '/self-system/login'" but can just "case '/login'" ?

Answer (score 1):

The `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable is the **entire** URI. So if are going to `http://example.com/example/login` the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable is `/example/login`. Something that you could try doing is changing your htaccess file to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/(.*)
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

(Note that `^/public/` will never match, because the `REQUEST_URI` would be `/example/public`)

Then in your code use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to hide PHP extension with the priority set to:

1. public directory
2. elsewhere

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip for existing files/directories (/assets will be skipped here)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# try to load PHP file from public directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /public/$1.php [L]

# now try .php elsewhere
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```